# Is saving PIL images after modifying necessary?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL module to get some data out of some images. I do this:

```
img = Image.open("example.jpg")
img = img.convert('L')
img.resize((800, 800))

data_list.append(np.array(img).flatten()/255)
```

I modify the image and then save the data that I want in a list. Is it okay to then just leave the image like this and not save it? because I don't really care about the image after I got the thing I want, so I prefer keep the images as it was. Is there a problem with changing an image and not saving it or I should do something to reset it?

Comment: You don't change the actual "image" in terms of the content of the opened file. You only manipulate some "image" in terms of some bytes stored in memory. So, you're fine not saving the changes. Your actual image file remains untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `img = Image.open("example.jpg")` PIL only loads a copy of the image into the memory. The actual image file stays untouched, so you don't need to add any additional code.

You can however delete the variable with `del img`, which can be useful, especially with bigger images to clear up the memory.